# Initializing UINavigationController with Coordinator Pattern and Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I am currently working on the migration of my app from MVC to MVVM. In addition I would like to use the Coordinator pattern. Since I use storyboards in my apps, I encountered a problem here.

I successfully implemented the instantiation of view controllers from the storyboard. But when I initialize the navigation controller `UINavigationController()` in the Coordinator, the app - of course - doesn't use the design of the navigation controller as I designed it in the storyboard.

Is there a way to initialize a Navigation Controller from the Storyboard similar to the View Controller `storyboard.inistantiateViewController(withIdentifier)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this an it works. Are you doing something like this?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let nc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController {
    print("got the nav controller")
}
// or if it's not the initial, you have to set the id in the storyboard
if let nc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Nav") as? UINavigationController {
    print("got the nav controller")
}
```

Comment: Well, that meens a navigation controller can be instantiated like a view controller and casted to UINavigationController? Is it really that simple?

Comment: It has to be a navigation controller in the storyboard for the downcast to work.